# R memory usage not decreasing after clearing workspace

Tags: r, memory, rstudio, pryr

I ran a large amount of calculations in R (using RStudio) and I'm confused about the state that this has left R in.  Specifically, after I ran

```
rm(list=ls(all.names = T))
```

and then

```
mem_used()
```

I am seeing that around 400 megabytes of space is being used.  Inspecting more closely with

```
gc(verbose = T)
```

I see the following:

Garbage collection 27693 = 26029+1296+368 (level 2) ...

95.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (31%)

331.6 Mbytes of vectors used (33%)

used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)

Ncells  1787624  95.5    5684620  303.6   5684620  303.6

Vcells 43457011 331.6  132000253 1007.1 262740244 2004.6

The question that I have is how do I figure out what is using all this space?  Specifically, the 330 Mb of vector storage is confusing to me given that I just rm'd all the user allocated objects.  Is it reasonable for R's internal structures to be consuming this much space?

Thanks for any help that anyone can provide.

Comment: The memory usage is one of the most annoying issues of Rstudio. Clearing the workspace doesn't help, restarting Rstudio does.

Comment: @RHA is so right. RStudio randomly hits peaks in memory usage. The only way I  have had success getting it back down is resetting.

Comment: I seriously doubt that rstudio is the culprit as much as R. Check out the links to the right of this question for various explanations / solutions.